# Android, Facebook SDK and Single Sign On: Either my App fails with "invalid_key" or Facebook App fails

Tags: android, single-sign-on, facebook

In November 2010 Facebook introduced Single-Sign-On for Android-Applications. Supposedly you can just login into your Facebook-App, and dont need to login again in your other applications, if you connect with Facebook-Login. However I experienced, that one of the Applications, either the Facebook-App, or my App fails with the login.

If the Facebook-App is installed, and I'm logged in, I cant log into my onw App, but instead get an error

```
"invalid_key"
```

If on the other hand, I first install my app, I'm logged into my App with Facebook-Login, and afterwards I install the Facebook App and try to logon their, the Facebook App fails and I cant login. Others seem to have the same issue: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/closed#issue/140

Is there anybody out there you ran into the same issue and solved it?

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be because of a number of reasons, most related to the wrong key-hash. I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489791/facebook-android-sdk-invalid-key/4496457#4496457).

Answer (score 0):

Are the set of permissions same in both the application?

Comment: I dont think you can add/limit permissions for the facebook App itself. My App just needs the publish-stream, and e-mail permission.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work for you, but OS X, Eclipse and running `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /Users/eosgood/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` and Enter keystore password: 'android' worked for me. if the pass isnt android, it failed. Hopefully this helps, this problem is a tough one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to facebook, now its giving key itself along with invalid_key exception.
Use that value and update in app settings. I am using windows 7 64 bit machine and for me the key doesn't have =(equal to) in the end but it worked cleanly.