# How to disable Facebook single sign on for android - Facebook-android-sdk

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, single-sign-on

SSO for facebook android gives me invalid_key every time, i tried to debug by every means but it is not working.
So is there any way/hack to disable Single Sign on and work with web view authenticating method even if Facebook App is installed on device...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ohh, Got answer make call to authorize method with activity code FACEBOOK.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH
mFacebook.authorize(activity, permissions, activityCode, listener);
replace activityCode with FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH

Comment: This was true before sdk version 3.x, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899955/how-to-disable-single-sign-on-for-facebook-android-app) worked for me using facebook sdk 3.5.1

Answer (score 4):

You likely don't want to use FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH as the solution because this disables the very useful Single Sign On feature completely.  Instead, if you go through the steps of setting up your application properly with Facebook, that should address the invalid_key issues.  You can find a detailed explanation of this on my blog:

http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/

Answer (score 1):

The invalid key issue could be because of a number of reasons, some of which I've detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489791/facebook-android-sdk-invalid-key/4496457#4496457) answer

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/SessionLoginBehavior/#SUPPRESS_SSO  This code worked well for me.