# Facebook keyhash error in my Android App

Tags: android

I have a problem when I try to login facebooj in my app with facebook. My app work good in simulator in Android Studio but after I uploaded my apk to Google Play and I try to login I get the following error:
Invalid key hash. The key hash .... does not match any stored key hash.
But in my simulator it works and I print my app key hash with some code and putted it in my Facebook Developer page.

If i delete my app from facebook applications and I login for first time, it works fine. But after I do a second login, I get the eroor "Invalid key hash"
Help me please...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301025/facebook-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes)

Comment: @mbmc This didn't help. I've removed face app and added the new hash key of android studio. It works on simulator but not on my phone...

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, this user suggest to create a new key and a new app, it seems work.

[Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301025/facebook-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes)

Comment: This didn't help. I've removed face app and added the new hash key of android studio. It works on simulator but not on my phone...

Comment: I fixed my question

Comment: Have you seen this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249889/logging-in-to-facebook-from-my-app-works-on-emulator-but-not-on-device

Comment: I cant ask from my users to uninstall facebook app and reinstall just to login my app right?