# How to get facebook authentication from Android login form

Tags: android, facebook

Is it possible to login into facebook using my own login form in Android & get the facebook user id? I just want to validate the users without need them access their facebook.

In the Android facebook tutorial, the app have to open facebook first so that user can login but there is no automatic close after user login successfully.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have a way to log the user in through facebook without using their official endpoints.

You can open some sort of browser with the [authentication dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) (or the [open graph one](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/)) but that still mean using their forms/ui (what ever you want to call it).

You should just use the [android sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) without using the SSO, that way the sdk won't call the facebook application that is installed on the device (if at all) and will just call the auth dialog for you.
This is a better solution for you since it "abstracts" some things from you, takes care of the access token and more.

Here's a thread about disabling the SSO: [How to disable Facebook single sign on for android - Facebook-android-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521013/how-to-disable-facebook-single-sign-on-for-android-facebook-android-sdk)