# Creating a new access token for facebook login using Android App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token

i'm implementing a app and need to login facebook account using a new access token.
what i required is, to get data from a specific facebook account.
I was able to find some coding about access token, but they all using the existing access token in facebook for android app.that's not what i required..
Help me guys,,,it's a life saving attempt.Hope u all undestand my requirement... Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want a different user to login to your app and not the one connected to facebook app.?

Comment: Yes subirkumarsao. Exactly'''

Answer (score 0):

If the device has the facebook application installed then calling the SSO will use that application and who ever is logged into that will be the user that is used.

You can avoid using SSO: [How to disable Facebook single sign on for android - Facebook-android-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521013/how-to-disable-facebook-single-sign-on-for-android-facebook-android-sdk) which will cause the SDK to use its' own dialog where the user can input his e-mail password.