# Share text on facebook without using Android Intent in app's background

Tags: android, facebook, future

i make one android app. i have list of product if i choose one product at that time that product share on Facebook with user name.

it is possible or not? if yes then how?

i was used share on Facebook using Android Intent in my previous app.

please help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `Intent` share.

then you need to implement Graph Api for facebook integration in your project.

For further reference [look here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Facebook Android SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/).

The sdk uses the [SSO](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso) which means that if the device has the facebook app installed then that app is in charge of authenticating the user against facebook, which is better since then the user does not need to input his email/password (which is not that fun on mobile devices), but it uses an intent to do so, if you want to avoid that: [How to disable Facebook single sign on for android - Facebook-android-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521013/how-to-disable-facebook-single-sign-on-for-android-facebook-android-sdk).

If you disable the SSO then the SDK will use its' own dialog to get the user's email/password.

In order to run things in the background you can use the [Async API Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/)