# android post only message on facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook

Now, I know that it's common question, but since "message" parameter is not valid, I wonder how to post just message to my facebook wall?
I use this:

```
public void postOnWall(Facebook mFacebook) {
try{
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("caption", "Caption");
    parameters.putString("description", "Description");

    mFacebook.dialog(this, "feed", params, new PostDialogListener());
}
catch(Exception e){}
}
```

I always get empty form without any title or content. I tried all params from [facebook sdk docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) but still no results.

UPD: when I say empty I mean this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why is the message parameter invalid?  If you want to only post a message on your wall its should simply be just a matter of doing the following:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "test message on my wall");
mAsyncRunner.request("feed", params, "POST", new PostDialogListener(), null);
```

Comment: it does nothing, empty form :/

Comment: Please paste any relevant logcat messages, this is the correct way to post a message on your own wall (I just tested it and verified it)

Comment: please look at the screenshot - no text inside the box, it's empty. And no error messages in logcat

Comment: By the way, have you looked at the link to facebook docs? "feed" api doesn't contain message parameter

Comment: Oh, you mean to pre-fill the message content for the user to post, here is the official answer to your question:

That is not possible because it is a violation of the Facebook Platform Policy, which you can read about here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/application_integration_points/) under Platform Policy IV.2.

That section is specifically meant for the user to fill out with their own voice, you can pre-populate the other content such as the captions, image, etc. but the message field cannot be filled out ahead of time.

Comment: Ah, thanks.. so what is the simplest way to post message then?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you with a way to automatically post to your own wall with a given message, can you try that and see if it works for you?

Comment: Hmm, my Facebook SDK doesn't even have AsyncFacebookRunner request with such params :) I'm using latest sdk

Comment: It was late at night and wasn't thinking correctly.  I forgot to put a null after the listener, that should work.  Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link of Stack overflow's answer for how to integrate facebook into your android application and if u have any query regarding that then tell me.

[Post status on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736205/share-text-on-facebook-without-using-android-intent-in-apps-background/10736377#10736377)

Comment: dude, it works weirdly - though I can share links using my code, I receive authourization error with your sample..

Comment: I just need a way to share TEXT instead of the links. Take a look at "Feed" api, there's no *message* param or similar, so my question was how to send just text? I use the latest Facebook SDK, *message* param is invalid since july 2012 afak.

Comment: @RomanTolmachev this example is working in my application and are you change application's "APP_ID"?

Comment: yeap, I just need to reauth with new permissions.. thanks anyway

Comment: @RomanTolmachev if this answer is helping you then accept this answer.