# how to do multiple facebook accounts login in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-oauth

I am creating an Android application by which user can post messages and updates their status on Facebook with the different Facebook accounts so is their any possibility to do multiple Facebook Login with the same(my) app, please provide me suggestions how can I do this in android.
Thanks..

Comment: multiple Facebook Login with the same time is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for response.. I don't want it on the same time but can user add multiple accounts please tell me.

Comment: your app is using facebook-sdk for only post status?

Comment: No I'm using OAuth flow for login purpose.

Comment: AFAIK, you absolutely cannot do it with Official FB SDK. And I'm not entirely sure if FB's privacy policy agrees to one person having multiple accounts. Just sayin..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the fb android sdk for authentication then the login is bound to the logged in user in the main facebook app (katana) on the mobile device (in case it's installed).

Even if you sign the user out from your application the next time he opens the application the same user will still be used since he is logged in using the facebook app.
Only if the user logs out of the facebook app and logs in using a different account, then your app will be able to use that account.

What you can do is to authenticate the user without the SSO.
In this case, which is like the case in which the facebook app is not installed on the device, the authentication is happening using the SDK which opens the oAuth dialog.
The problem with this approach is that the user needs to enter his e-mail and password, which is not that much fun task to do with most mobile devices.
If you decide to go with this approach read this thread: [How to disable Facebook single sign on for android - Facebook-android-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521013/how-to-disable-facebook-single-sign-on-for-android-facebook-android-sdk)