# How can I create multiple-user access accounts on Facebook Android application.?

Tags: android, facebook, multiple-accounts

I have created an android app for Facebook integration with single user Login. Now i want Multiple user Login in the same application. How can i do this. Please give some suggestions with any android code or usable link. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: are you saving your FB cradentials in SharedPrefs.

Comment: Dont Save them.. so you can be able to login with diff. Users. or is your requirement is different.

Comment: @PrashantMishra There's no saving of the "credentials", the facebook sdk takes care of that, the app can only save access token, but that's not the problem. This is a facebook issue, not android.

Comment: Please explain it by any example.i m not able to understand how i use my app without saving them.

Comment: yes i have saved access_token and access_expires in sharedpreference.

Comment: hey..help me how can i login from my app with multiple user at a time.?????

Comment: Wait, you want to have more than one user logged in to use at the same time?

Comment: at a time only one user can login.

Answer (score 2):

The facebook android SDK is trying to use the [SSO](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso) if the device has the facebook application (katana) installed.
If the SSO is used then you have no way of doing so, the `authorize` method will always use the logged in user in the katana and so you'll have to ask the user to manually logout in the main facebook application.

What you can do is call `authorize` without the sso as expalined here: [How to disable Facebook single sign on for android - Facebook-android-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521013/how-to-disable-facebook-single-sign-on-for-android-facebook-android-sdk).