# Facebook Log In Using Dialog and Not Native Log In Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have been searching for the approach on how to log in in facebook using web dialog. I am working with this so that the native facebook app[whenever it is installed in the device], will not be affected. By the way, all I want to achieve is to log in using dialog using facebook sdk version 3. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SDK 3.0, you need to do it via an OpenRequest, something like:

```
Session s = new Session(this);
Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
request.setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {...});
request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO); // <-- this is the important line
s.openForRead(request);
Session.setActiveSession(s);
```

Comment: Thank you @Ming Li but after logging in with facebook using web dialog, the native log in for facebook appeared since I requested for publishpermissions and it says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000366/android-facebook-publishpermissions-without-retyping-password-when-using-suppr) that there is a bug. So still, it affects the facebook native app on my phone. Have you found some solution about this? Thank you.

Comment: Two questions. 1. Are you setting the SessionLoginBehavior again when you're making the new permissions request? 2. Are you using the latest 3.0.1 version of the SDK (where the bug you linked to was addressed)?

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to set the property **SessionLoginBehavior**, If you are using the facebook login button as described by the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/), then you just have to set the property of login button like this:

```
loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

and if you are logging in with out fb login button then you can just set the property of **OpenRequest** object you should be providing to open the session.

```
 openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

Look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/SessionLoginBehavior/) for other login behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
```

It does not use your native app login for sure.