# how to configure disable Single SIgn On for facebook sdk 3.0 for android?

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I have created an android app for Facebook and login with "com.facebook.LoginActivity" this method login with app of facebook and i need login independent.

Something similar to this question
[How to disable Single SIgn On for facebook android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899955/how-to-disable-single-sign-on-for-facebook-android-app)
I need some examples..
I would greatly appreciate your help....sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using LoginButton (as in the HelloFacebookSample), you can disable SSO like so:

```
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

Otherwise, You will have to set the SessionLoginBehavior similarly.

Answer (score 1):

For the SDK 4 you need to set `setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);`