# facebook working on emulator not on device

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Its working perfectly on emulator but not on device.
crashing at `response = read(conn.getInputStream());`  in facebook sdk.

Comment: Did u add the permission to manifest ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Probably the Single Sign on issue

Comment: can somebody help me on this page:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813922/facebook-android-sdk-integration

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I had this issue,

It worked fine on the emulator, worked fine on my dev phone, but failed on the test users phone.

It's to do with the Facebook app and SSO.

Have a read of this : http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/

It has 3 solutions.

I couldn't get SSO to work so I went for option two, (opt out of SSO!) This is done by:

facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, this);
If you want to fix it and get SSO to work:

Correctly generate your hash key for the debug apk certificate. (detailed in the link above).

Ref:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158056/1838457

Comment: Using `FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH` is **not recommended** as it **may open up your app to malicious apps that can steal your user's Facebook credentials** (SOURCE: Answer by *Jesse Chen*, who works at Facebook. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12433933/450534.