# Android facebook sdk implementation fails "an error occurred"

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm programming an Android App that should use the Facebook SDK to add some social interaction with Facebook.

My problem is, that the Authentication fails each time I try to run the app.

The only error message I get is: "An error occurred. Please try again later."

My call looks like that:

```
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook("MyAppID");

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    facebook.authorize(this, permissions, new LoginDialogListener());
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```

I have genereated my debugkey as described and it did work once... but only once! Since then I'm getting this error even after I uninstall the app.

Anyone who has that error too and may have found a solution?

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
Got it back to work... no clue how.

I'll update this post if I find out why.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129308/an-errors-occurred-when-authenticating-with-facebooks-android-sdk) Maybe this provides a solution?

Comment: I actually did have that same problem at the beginning but it's not the same anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem where it worked once and then stopped working. I changed nothing, just restarted the phone and it worked again! Logged out/in again and it worked fine.

Very strange.

## Edit

Further observation shows that this *only* occurs when the facebook app is not installed. I'm guessing it is some facebook bug, maybe related to cookies or something.

Comment: As far as I can remember, I fixed it by rewriting everything from scratch... not a really good solution but then it worked!

Comment: Restarting the device after uninstalling Facebook app fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that for `"MyAppID"` you need to use the App ID that Facebook assigned you when you created your account - not the Android Key Hash that you generated using the `keytool`.

Go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps`.  At the top left is a value, `App ID/API Key`.  *This* is the value you should enter when you construct your new `Facebook` object with

`Facebook facebook = new Facebook("4123532123123")`.

Enter the `keytool` value into Facebook's configuration page, enter the App ID into your application.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he had already done that! (Otherwise it wouldn't work at all.) I have the same symptoms as him (worked once but never again) and I have my ID set correctly.