# Android Invalid Key error, Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall, facebook-android-sdk

I have created an Android application that uses `Facebook SDK` to make wall posts. It works fine on devices that don't have the native Facebook App installed, but when it is, it throws an *Invalid Key* error.
I have checked all the settings & keys from my facebook application and my device code twice and all is setup right. What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you even Google this or search for other questions? http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7979389/facebook-android-invalid-key

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129308/an-errors-occurred-when-authenticating-with-facebooks-android-sdk/6133971#6133971

Answer (score 1):

You received this error because of wrong hash calculated on your app. During application execution calculated hash value is send to facebook. If value is different from value you set in facebook developer profile - problem. If you cannot calculate correctly - read it from error message and put it to facebook developer profile. I made the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem because of the hash key. You ca find out the hash key of your app from this link

[Facebook Integration in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730848/facebook-integration-in-android-application/16734424#16734424)

and can update it in facebook app.