# Facebook API Exception

Tags: android, facebook

i just implemented Facebook log in into my android application. when i try to log in with Facebook i got following exception in log-cat.

**Error Log :**

```
com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash oZgj_um2MGi1eYpfTqwytjLMN10 does not match any stored key hashes
```

I already added this key hash into my developer account app page.But still i am facing same issue.

Comment: This is my logcat 01-23 13:42:12.539: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5222): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash oZgj_um2MGi1eYpfTqwytjLMN10 does not match any stored key hashes.

Comment: remove old one And add new hask key..

Comment: already tried with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your HashKey is wrong. It should have **28 characters** while your hash key 27 characters the hashkey always **ends with =**. So I think you have missed it. Please check it again and 
Change your hashkey by generating it programatically from the following code given in Facebook Docs and defined at  [Facebook Integration in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730848/facebook-integration-in-android-application/16734424#16734424)

```
PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.yourpackagename", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
        Log.e("hash key", something);
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```