# Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token

Tags: android, facebook

Using the FB SDK for Android sometimes it throws me error in Logcat.

Anyone knows the reason? My app is running and approved (Not on google play). I'm also using the hash thing and have my main activity and package name listed on the FB app page.

Comment: This usually means you're passing in a null Session to the Request. Are there cases where you're making graph Requests, but have not initialized the session yet?

Comment: Try this simple fix, it worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21329790/771922

Comment: I am also facing similar problem.

Comment: similar problem, any solutions for it?

Comment: Facing same problem. I am using parse.com SDK along with facebook SDK to login facebook. Did anyone find solution?

Comment: Anyone found an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think the facebook account that you use to share, hasn't a role in your facebook app. Go to your app developer facebook console and check Roles. Or set status and review to ON but I think it's not the good solution if your app isn't available on Google Play or App Store

Comment: any solution if the app is not available on the play store?

Comment: @NiteshVerma Even if the app is not available on app store, you still need to add the account that you use to share in one of the roles.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your Hash Key in Settings at https://developers.facebook.com
Try the code below to check and add correct hashkey.
It work for me!!!

> ```
> private void getSHAFingerPrint(){
>       PackageInfo info;
>       try {
>
>           info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
>                   "your.package", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
>
>           for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
>               MessageDigest md;
>               md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
>               md.update(signature.toByteArray());
>               String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
>               Log.e("Hash key", something);
>               System.out.println("Hash key" + something);
>           }
>
>       } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
>           Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
>       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
>           Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           Log.e("exception", e.toString());
>       }
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851484/3552317, is a solution that works for some peaple (and duplicate question) and this worked for me:

This worked for me:

```
       <string name="app_id">999999999999999</string>
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Comment: when i add this, i'm getting xml parsing error,  Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Comment: The first line goes into the strings.xml file, the latter three in AndroidManifest.xml. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading#20to30

Answer (score 1):

You got this error log because your session is expired, and you need call login again, it'll automatic login with user-authorized account and wouldn't promt user to accept the app's pubic permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you have might not declare your application id in manifest.xml or you have not properly registered your application on "*developers.facebook.com*"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an question but I just solved my issue by going to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[yourappid]/settings/ and disabling the option `Deep Linking`.

Hope this helps someone :).