# how I can post "Watching movie" status in facebook wall with opengraph

Tags: android, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk, movies

I'm working android facebook sdk. I learn and I can login. now I want to post watching movie status in my wall.
I googled and I found facebook documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.wants_to_watch/

I tried this code

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("other", "http://samples.ogp.me/467235199955838");
params.putString("movie", "http://samples.ogp.me/453907197960619");
params.putString("tv_show", "http://samples.ogp.me/413802348663468");
params.putString("episode", "http://samples.ogp.me/335419676534648");

new Request(
    session,
    "/me/video.wants_to_watch",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

and session is

```
import com.facebook.Session;
private Session session;
```

when I run my app and try to post to wall I have like this log message

```
Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.
```

how I can add access token and application ID?

if anyone knows solution please help me

thanks

Comment: Did you search for the error? Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722465/warning-sessionless-request-needs-token-but-missing-either-application-id-or-cl

Comment: yes i searched.i added meta-data in manifest file but nothink changed @thegrinner