# Integration Facebook SSO is not working

Tags: android

I am integrating Facebook SSO and it was working fine with my two of the apps and now when i am configuring it with my third app its just not working. Below is my errors i am getting in the logcat. please anyone help me out.

```
     09-22 18:01:38.885: E/ActivityThread(10499): Failed to find provider info for  com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
     09-22 18:02:19.805: E/ActivityThread(10499): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
     09-22 18:02:19.815: E/ActivityThread(10499): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider
     09-22 18:02:29.674: D/dalvikvm(10499): GC_EXPLICIT freed 561K, 45% free 3422K/6151K, external 5536K/6743K, paused 76ms
     09-22 18:02:38.753: D/Request(10499): Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.
```

Comment: You are missing the application_id which facebook provides when you  create application over their.

Comment: No its not that, i used the application id which facebook is providing.

Comment: Then the problem will be of keyhash, this may help you- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848067/login-failed-invalid-key-error-with-facebook-sdk/4851484#4851484

Comment: Actually i generated the keyhash and its created but then too its not working so i created the keyhash 2 to 3 times so not sure which will work.

Comment: I want to ask you one question.. when we write the keytool command in command prompt and when we have to add the password at that time do we need to put our app signing password or the default password "android"  ?

Comment: I have faced this problem while creating keyhash from windows 7 / 8 machine. Try using cygwin and create keyhash with that. it solved my problem. hope it helps !

Comment: If you are generating keyhash for debug purpose then you can use android password else you have to use your signing password.

Comment: i am using my signing password but its not generating any keyhash now just asking for the password but not generating any key

Comment: I am using this command in cmd prompt : C:\Documents and Settings\admin>keytool -exportcert -alias aliasname -keystore path of my signed keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base6
4

Answer (score 0):

Follow the tutorial and exmaple might be you missed out some steps its worked for me:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Comment: These is what i worked and got two successful applications uploaded to store but there is something which is not working in this app.