# I get this warning "Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token"

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Hi I have Facebook login integration with Android and when I click the login button I get this warning :

> "Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or
>   client token."

The application ID and keyHash are fine. I have login integration from official Facebook documentation.

Please help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your facebook app id in your code by going here https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android  get the facebook app id by following those tutorial. Then use it in your code like this

```
<string name="app_id">27368237928798</string>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Comment: I followed that tutorial, here are more details :
11588-11588/com.pegyx.app E/SensorManager﹕ thread start
09-28 00:42:25.156  11588-11588/com.pegyx.app D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 1598182229  name= BOSCH BMC150 Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000
09-28 00:42:25.179  11588-11620/com.pegyx.app D/Request﹕ Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.
09-28 00:42:29.093  11588-11588/com.pegyx.app D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener::
09-28 00:42:29.093  11588-11588/com.pegyx.app D/Sensors﹕ Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms

Comment: my manifest :
 <string name="app_id">xxxxxxxxx</string>
       <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
I forced the webDialog login with 
"authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);" 

 and I solved the problem just for a few days. Now I give Facebook permission to my app and it closes. I get this logCat  :

<GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M> 

¡help me please!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was solved by manually input the key hash at the app setting in http://developer.facebook.com/apps/{your_app_id_number}/settings/

It appears that the "quick starts" wizard does not really store the hash you write and no identification is possible. At least tested with the HelloFacebookSample included in SDK 3.21.1 https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Do not need to uninstall FB app as stated in
[Login failed invalid key error with Facebook SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848067/login-failed-invalid-key-error-with-facebook-sdk)