# Invalid Api-key cause facebook login error?

Tags: android, facebook

I created a Facebook application and added API key into key hash but
still Facebook login shows failed due to Invalid key.

My application is ready but this is the problem causing in delay of publishing my application.

Comment: pls explain how did you generate your key?

Comment: i followed all steps given on facbook developer site.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489791/facebook-android-sdk-invalid-key/4496457#4496457 - your key hash may be incorrect in your app settings

Comment: the steps that i followed to get key hash are
1.copied all file from OpenSSl into jdk
2.set path to C:/programfiles/java/jdk/bin in command prompt
3.then run= keytool -export -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "[PATH]\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
4.got hash key +ZRWQIs5LsdDsBNdoJ8wT2RyYrE=
5.copied into native android app in hash key
but still error occurred
plz help me

Answer (score 0):

After creating your Facebook application, it'll generate an API-key to use.
This is the key you'll need.

If I'm correct you can still find it somewhere on your Application page on Facebook.

Not sure if the api-key is equal too the application ID.

Comment: i also used that one in my apps but still same error occurring

Comment: is it necessary to add namespace and apps domain in application setting?

Comment: Doesn't know.. you should check developer.facebook.com , maybe you can get some info from the documentary of FB.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one

```
Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH
```

and it worked.