# isSessionValid() returns NO when Facebook native application is installed

Tags: single-sign-on, facebook-android-sdk

I have an issue with SSO using the Facebook SDK for Android. The problem occurs **only** when the native Facebook application is installed. When it's not installed, everything works fine, specifically:

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
facebook.authorize(mActivity, , new DialogListener() {
   ...
});

facebook.isSessionValid(); // returns true
```

But when the native application is installed, `facebook.isSessionValid()` still returns `false` despite the fact that I called the `authorize` method.

I should add that I created an native Android based Facebook application with the hashkey generated from my debug certificate using `keytool`.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

What is going on?

Comment: same here. did you happen to solve this?

Comment: Tested on 4.0.3 and 2.3.4. I have created a bug report here http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/166465130126268 but apparently they say it should work. Need to read the documentation again and find what is causing the issue.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489791/facebook-android-sdk-invalid-key/4496457#4496457 and here: http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/ . I got the same Login failed: invalid_key error in my logcat, so these may provide the right solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLVED! :)

I sure hope this will work for you as well.
The problem is that Windows generates an invalid key.

Run this with your app:

```
try {
   PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("**YOURPACKAGENAME**", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
   for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.i("PXR", Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
   }
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}
```

Don't forget to get Base64 (http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/).

The generated key is on your logcat, replace the old one with this.

Solution thanks to:
http://p-xr.com/implementing-facebook-into-your-app-invalid-key-with-keytool/

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) However, turns out I was using the right signature even before. It's killing me!

Comment: @Amokrane Chentir :) weird... I wonder what else this error can be.

Comment: Yes! It was definitely an issue in my code, a very stupid one! I was using inheritance and one onActivityResult was overriding the other. Hence: `facebook.authorizeCallback` wasn't called.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Lior wrote

you can do the log like this:

```
Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

so you can use Andorid Base64

ref: [Invalid Key Hash Troubleshooting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#protip1)