# How to overcome the issue of getting the login from a Facebook application?

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook SDK in hackbook and tried to login and do all the operations in the hackbook. It works fine. And after installing the Facebook application for Android, when I click on login it does not return data in `onActivityResult`. It returns null in intent data.

The Facebook application is already logged in with my ID and when I try Facebook login with some other application, it is working fine. Do I have to give any extra permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably an invalid hash key error (the hash key you generated and inserted on the Facebook application page)...

See [my answer to a similar Stack Overflow question, *isSessionValid() returns NO when Facebook native application is installed*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805843/issessionvalid-returns-no-when-facebook-native-app-installed/9081059#9081059).

I hope this helps.